# How to do country specific google search using CSE?

Tags: google-search, google-search-api, google-custom-search

I want do country specific search using google search engine in .Net. I have followed the article [here](http://hintdesk.com/c-how-to-use-google-custom-search-api/) which shows how to do it. So I got the API Key. However I'm not sure how do get search engine id for specific google search engine
for example I want to search "keyword" using the following google web sites

```
https://www.google.com/  
https://www.google.co.in/  
https://www.google.co.uk/  
https://www.google.com.br/
```

Do I need to create Search Engine ID for each of this URL?  When I goto https://cse.google.com/cse/all and click on Add Search Engine
After this where do I configure google's search URL?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search just one country, you can set it in your account, and no need to update the code:

https://cse.google.com/ > Search features > Advanced > Websearch Restricts  > Country Restrict
[image: CSE Country Restrict]

If you want to search multiple countries:

[CSharp API > Google.Apis.Customsearch.v1.CseResource.ListRequest.Cr](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/customsearch/v1/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Customsearch_1_1v1_1_1CseResource_1_1ListRequest.html#a32a41e0e405fd0508d418a759f858c86)

[XML API reference appendices > boolean-operators](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/xml_results_appendices#boolean-operators)

I guess you'll try with `countryUS|countryIN|countryUK|countryBR`

Answer (score 0):

as per google documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/reference/cse/list) I have to set `googlehost` parameter

> The local Google domain (for example, google.com, google.de, or google.fr) to use to perform the search.

Comment: Glad to hear you have that sorted, but I think that is not "_country specific search_".

Comment: I may have the wrong subject line. I should have said google host specific search :)